# Wxpython passing data from one frame to another

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a text control, a choice control, and a button on one from. I would like to pass the values of both the text control and the choice control to another frame when button is pressed. In the on_press method in the code below, I returned both values as a list. How can I access this list in PanelTwo. Here's the code:

```
import wx

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self,label = "Your Name:" ,style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        box.Add(self.label, 1 , wx.EXPAND |wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL |wx.ALL, 20)

        self.inputTxtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self,wx.ID_ANY,value='')

        box.Add(self.inputTxtOne, 1 , wx.EXPAND |wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL |wx.ALL, 20)

        languages = ['ZIRA', 'DAVID']

        chlbl = wx.StaticText(self,label = "Voice control",style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE) 

        box.Add(chlbl,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        self.choice = wx.Choice(self,choices = languages)

        box.Add(self.choice,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label='Submit',style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW)

        btn.SetFont(wx.Font(15,wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL))

        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press)

        box.Add(btn,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL,5)

        self.SetSizer(box)

        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press)        

    def on_press(self,event):

        name = self.inputTxtOne.GetValue()
        voice_choice = self.choice.GetValue()
        nv_list = [name,voice_choice]

        parent_frame = self.GetParent()
        parent_frame.Close()
        frame = FrameTwo()
        frame.Show()       

        return nv_list        


class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self,label = "Your Name is "+name ,style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        box.Add(self.label, 1 , wx.EXPAND |wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL |wx.ALL, 20)

        self.SetSizer(box)


class FrameOne(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="First Frame")
        panel = PanelOne(self)
        self.Show()

class FrameTwo(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Second Frame")
        panel = PanelTwo(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = FrameOne()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. Let's go step by step.

First of all, the variable called "name" in PanelOne, must be part of the class instead of a local variable of the "on_press" method:

Change:

```
name = self.inputTxtOne.GetValue()
voice_choice = self.choice.GetValue()
```

by:

```
# Notice the use of self. In this way, we can access it from anywhere in the class
self.name = self.inputTxtOne.GetValue()
# What version of wx are you using? Get the choices value with GetSelection() method.
voice_choice = self.choice.GetSelection()
```

Now we need to access this variable from another class (PanelTwo). For this, we will pass an instance of the PanelOne class to the second frame (Frame2) and we will store it as a member variable (with the use of self, as we saw in the previous example).

```
# When you instantiate the Frame2 in PanelOne must pass the self instance of PanelOne
frame = FrameTwo(self)
```

Then in **init** method in Frame2:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Second Frame")

    #Now the reference to PanelOne is a member varialble of class Frame2.
    self.panelOne = parent

    #Pass Frame2 instance (self) to PanelTwo in constructor:
    panel = PanelTwo(self)

    # Rest of your code...
```

Finally in PanelTwo:

```
class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self)

        # parent is Frame2. 
        # panelOne is a public and member variable of Frame2 that references to PanelOne instance.
        # name is a member and accesible variable of PanelOne.

        print(parent.panelOne.name)
```

A recommendation: use WxGlade for make best code. With it you can learn a lot about how things are done in wxpython.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. However, I think you need to change print(parent.frame1.name) to print(parent.PanelOne.name) and wx.Panel.__init__(self) to wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent).

Comment: @MohamedThiab, Thank you for the correction. You're right. I changed the name of that variable at the end but not in all places: P